# Node.js unset environment variable

Tags: node.js

How do you unset an environment variable in Node.js?

I've tried:

```
process.env.MYVAR = undefined
```

But that doesn't unset it, it appears as follows:

```
console.log('xx' + process.env.MYVAR + 'xx');
```

Output is:

> xxundefinedxx

I want:

> xxxx

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is another unintuitive aspect to it: Node.js converts `undefined` to the string "undefined" when assigning an environment variable:

```
> process.env.MYVAR = undefined
undefined
> typeof process.env.MYVAR
'string'
```

You can work around this using `delete`:

```
> delete process.env.MYVAR
true
> typeof process.env.MYVAR
'undefined'
```

Tested with Node.js 10.18, 12.14, 13.5 and 16.15.

For this reason `(process.env.MYVAR || '')` does not help, as it evaluates to `('undefined' || '')`.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that:

```
console.log('xx' + process.env.MYVAR + 'xx');
```

Is actually incorrect. The value of an undefined property is `undefined`. `process.env.MYVAR = undefined` is the same as `delete process.env.MYVAR` in so far as the value of the property is the same. But properties also have a presence that `delete` removes, in that the key will not show up in the `Array` returned by `Object.keys`.

If you want the empty string, instead you must write:

```
console.log('xx' + (process.env.MYVAR || '') + 'xx');
```

Comment: delete process.env.MYVAR works - setting it to undefined does not work - many thanks - PS I am not sure the question I asked reflects my situation 100% truly - but anyway this answer does the job :D

Comment: Setting an object property to `undefined` isn't quite the same as deleting it, e.g. `'x' in {} // false` vs. `'x' in {x:undefined} // true`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147167/2013738 why delete works and setting to undefined does not. ping @danday74

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you understand that `undefined !== ""`

Use this: `process.env.MYVAR = ""` if you want an empty string. undefined means there is nothing there. An empty string means there is the text of nothing to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to clear a local environment variable is by using `unset` command (Linux/Mac). To unset any local environment variable temporarily:

```
$ unset <var-name>
```

where `<var-name>` is the name of local variable which you want to unset or clear.

Answer (score -2):

For you who uses windows, setting the variable works like following on the command line:

```
SET MYVAR=value
```

Getting the variable works like

```
SET MYVAR
```

And lastly, to answer the question here, unsetting it:

```
SET MYVAR=
```

Comment: More specifically, you're attempting to use `cmd.exe`'s syntax (in PowerShell, it would be `$env:MYVAR = 'value'`), but your examples are broken: there must be no spaces around `=`